# How to use the output of a command as a variable in a script?

Tags: scripting

I need the following script to look at the running processes on the server to use as the below hard coded variables (`orauser` and `orasid`)

```
#!/bin/bash
orauser="oraqa1"
orasid="ERPQA1"
source /home/$orauser/$orasid.env
su - ${orauser}   << BOF 2>&1
export ORACLE_SID=$orasid
sqlplus /nolog << EOF 2>&1
connect / as sysdba
alter database begin backup;
exit;
EOF
BOF
```

What the best way to do this?

I can get the actual output I need by running `ps`

which will show the `orauser` (`oradev`) at the beginning and the `orasid` (`ERPDEV`) at the END (after the last underscore).

eg

```
:~$ps -ef |grep pmon
oradev   22733     1  0 03:36 ?        00:00:05 ora_pmon_ERPDEV
```

If it fails, then the script wont run - which is fine because that means there is probably no database on that server...

whats the cleanest/neatest way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
$ output="$(ps -ef |grep pmon)"
```

The output of `ps -ef |grep pmon` will be stored in a variable named `$output`.

Comment: Thanks - that part helps for the user - but for the SID

How could I parse out everything in this line:

oradev   22733     1  0 03:36 ?        00:00:05 ora_pmon_ERPDEV

to display ONLY the ERPDEV at the end?

the output is always AFTER the last UNDERSCORE

-thanks